# Python: How could I extract an specific value from a dictionary within a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I am receiving the following result after calling reverse_geocoder function and I'd like to retrieve the value of 'name' key into a single variable. How could I do to get that?.

```
[{'lat': '-34.57365',
  'lon': '-58.44924',
  'name': 'Colegiales',
  'admin1': 'Buenos Aires F.D.',
  'admin2': '',
  'cc': 'AR'}]
```

I am trying with the following code but I m getting an error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str":

```
For index, row in df_dummies[mask_nulls].iterrows():
    a = (row['lat'], row['lon'])
    address = rg.search(a)
    suburb = address['name']
    barrios.append(address)
```

Thanks

Comment: That's a list, which means it may have more than one dictionary in it or maybe none at all. What do you expect to happen if there is more than one? How will you handle an empty list? You can just grab the first element: `address[0]['name']` but that's an error with an empty list.

Comment: `for item in result: item['name']`

Comment: after the sentence "rg.searach(a)" who is returnin a list with 1 element I d like to extract only the value of the key 'name' which contains the suburb, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You only have to create a reference variable to the list[0]. Then you can use the dictionary['name'] to extract the value.

Answer (score 0):

As you can notice 'address' is a list and not dictionary. In case if you are sure that the list always contains only one dictionary, You could use this

```
address[0]['name']
```